# Azure AD B2C - Storing profile information in Salesforce?

Tags: azure, salesforce, azure-active-directory, identity, azure-ad-b2c

I want to implement a process along the lines of;

1. Staff member creates Salesforce Contact
2. Personalised registration link is sent to client
3. Client registers for the web application with Azure AD
4. Client fills in profile information which is stored against the SF Contact
5. Web application has access to logged in client's profile information

My initial thoughts were to send an identifier for the SF Contact in the registration link which is then attached to the AD user (does AD support custom attributes during signup?). When the user signs into the web app and completes their profile, update the Contact using the Salesforce REST api. Profile data would then also be pulled into the web app as required via the same means.

Is there a better approach to this problem?